# Disabling filtering including nested <filterset> elements in ANT 'copy' task

Tags: ant, filtering

Requirement:
We have one ANT build file which is used to for both DEV and RELEASE mode. We would like to enable filtering in DEV mode and disable it in RELEASE mode. As we are using the same build file for both modes(DEV and RELEASE) hence we are looking for ways to switch on/off filtering based on build mode.

My analysis so far:
As per documentation, the filtering can be disabled but the nested  elements will always be used, even if this attribute is false.  http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html
Please note that we can't move away from  elements in our case.

Question:
I would like to know if there is a workaround to disable filtering including nested  elements in 'copy' task .

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the effect of having no filterset by having one that does nothing.
[Filtersets support id/refids](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html), so you can define two - one dev and one release - then switch between them using a condition based on the mode.  Something like this:

```
<property name="mode" value="release" /><!--Or value="dev"-->

<filterset id="dev.filter.id">
    <filter token="MODE" value="dev" />
</filterset>

<filterset id="release.filter.id" /><!--Null filterset-->

<!--Choose filterset id depending on mode-->   
<condition property="copy.filter.id"
           value="dev.filter.id"
           else="release.filter.id">
    <equals arg1="${mode}" arg2="dev"/>
</condition>

<copy file="input.txt" tofile="output.txt">
    <filterset refid="${copy.filter.id}" />
</copy>
```

If you have a number of behaviours that differ between dev and release modes, it might make sense to put those in separate build configuration files and load just the one for the current mode.

Comment: Thank you fr prompt response. The approach that you have suggested would work if there are only one occurance of conditional <filterset>. To be more clear on my requirement, in my case there are more than one occurances of <filterset> where the token and value of <filter> within <filterset> differs and I have to enable or disable <filterset> at several places across the build file. Do your suggest a solution for the aforesaid problem?